# How to sort by (dropdown from toolbar.phtml) products which has special price comes first on product list (search or category) page?

Tags: magento-1.7, price, frontend, product-list

On product list page want option in sort by dropdown discounted first products so all prodcuts in list with special price comes first.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to filter on an attribute in the product list you can edit the value `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` for that attribute.

Go to `Backend > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` filter on `Attribute code` **Special price** and click it.

Then scroll down until you see the option `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` and set that to yes. Refresh your cache and indexes afterwards.

[image]